# Как нормализовать пробелы после innerText в HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#

Вот фрагмент Html кода:

```
    <div>
    <div>
        <a></a>
        <a></a>
        <div><a><span></span>Text1</a></div>
    </div>
        <div>Text2</div>
    </div>
```

C помощью:

```
var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("*");

foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
{
   text += node.InnerText;
}
```

Я получаю такую строку:

```
"\r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        Text1\r\n                    Text2"
```

Могу ли я выдернуть просто текст ?

```
"Text1 Text2"
```

Comment: `SelectNodes("//text()[normalize-space(.) != '']")`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Блин, я же забыл что можно применить Xpach и в этом моменте, спасибо большое, ещё долго ходил бы не тем путём.

Comment: Можно без xpath, с использованием LINQ: `Descendants().OfType<HtmlTextNode>().Where(n => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(n.InnerText))`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, до LINQ ещё не дошёл в изучении.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov уточняющий вопрос, а без  использования конкатенации я могу получить текст сразу всего фрагмента ? Пробую разные манипуляции, ничего не выходит `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//text()[normalize-space(.)]").InnerText;` В `DocumentNode` именно тот фрагмент `Html`  что сверху.

Comment: Думаю, без конкатенации никак. `SelectSingleNode` возвращает одну-единственную ноду, то есть не весь текст. `SelectNodes` возвращает набор узлов, которые потом нужно конкатенировать. Можно просто взять `DocumentNode.InnerText` - это вернет текст всех узлов уже конкатенированный, но с пробельными символами. Как вариант, можно убрать их потом регуляркой.

Comment: Кстати, если не нравится конкатенация в цикле, используйте `string.Join` - `string.Join(" ", htmlNodes.Select(n => n.InnerText))`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83213/discussion-between-vipz-and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string text = "\r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        \r\n                        Text1\r\n                    Text2";

        var str3 = new String(text.Where(ch => ch != '\r' && ch != '\n').ToArray()).Trim();
        var str4 = str3.Split(' ').Where(ch => ch != String.Empty).ToArray();
        string finalstring = String.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i <= str4.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i != str4.Length - 1)
                finalstring += str4[i] + " ";
            else
                finalstring += str4[i];

        }
```

Comment: Здорово! Это во всех случаях работает для меня, а нельзя это всё заменить одним xpath ? Наверняка же можно, но чёт я не могу подобрать ключ `text = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//text()[normalize-space(.)]").InnerText;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str3 = new String(text.Where(ch => ch != '\r' && ch != '\n').ToArray()).Trim();
```

Comment: Вам нужен один пробел между частями строки?

Comment: `//*[normalize-space()='" + text + "'][last()]`